# Read a xlsx file using apache poi in java? not working

Tags: java

I have used all poi jars but still i ame getting this error

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.POIXMLException:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>         at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:62)
>         at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:456)
>         at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:162)
>         at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.(XSSFWorkbook.java:271)
>         at ReadExcel.readXLSXFile(ReadExcel.java:38)
>         at ReadExcel.main(ReadExcel.java:69)
>       Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>         at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:60)
>         ... 5 more
>       Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/POIXMLTypeLoader
>         at org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.ThemeDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown
>   Source)
>         at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.ThemesTable.(ThemesTable.java:46)
>         ... 10 more
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.POIXMLTypeLoader
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>         ... 12 more

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you do not have the correct dependencies in you project.
POIXMLTypeLoader comes with POI 3.14-Beta1 and the ooxml-schemas:1.3 reference that class.You have the following options, you can add any of this dependency in your project:

- **use poi 3.14 beta1**

  ```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.14</version>
  </dependency>
  ```
- **use ooxml-schemas 1.2**

  ```
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
   <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
   <version>3.14</version>
  </dependency>
  ```